# Raster processing for climate change model

Tags: python, python-2.x, geospatial, scipy, arcpy

I am working on a project on how climate change may affect the development of spruce budworm larvae throughout each year (historical and projected) using different climate change models and emission scenarios.

The code that I have works, but would take a ridiculous amount of time to run: 38 years when extrapolated out. I'm using python 2.7.12 on a 64-bit windows machine with 24GB RAM and xeon processors. So, I don't think machine specs are an issue... it's how my script is written and organized.

I'm fairly new to Python, and have read through some articles on NumPy arrays and scipy packages, but do not have the knowledge/skills on how to implement them in this script to optimize the raster processing. Is numpy or scipy the way to go, and can those packages accomplish what I am trying to do?

Each time a new 4-h timestep raster is accessed, 27 conditional statements are executed, which probably is the reason the script runs so slow. Does anyone see a way to reduce the amount of conditional statements, but achieve the same goal?

Any help on how to improve the overall performance so that the script runs in a reasonable amount of time would be greatly appreciated!

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
import math

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('spatial')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

ClimateModels = ["CanESM2", "CSIRO-Mk3-6-0", "HadGEM2-ES"]
ConcentrationPathway = ["rcp26", "rcp45", "rcp85"]

#100 random numbers between 0.4 and 2.5, representing the stochastic growth rates of individual spruce budworm larvae ....need to be the same each time it loops through GCM+RCP combination
BudwormList = [2.1, 2.3, 0.6, 2.1, 1.7, 1.1, 1.6, 2.4, 2.1, 2.2, 0.9, 1.6, 0.6, 2.0, 1.7, 0.6, 0.7, 1.8, 1.3, 2.4,
           2.1, 0.8, 2.2, 1.6, 0.5, 1.0, 1.6, 2.4, 2.5, 2.5, 0.8, 0.5, 2.5, 0.9, 1.2, 0.7, 1.8, 1.8, 0.4, 1.9,
           0.8, 1.3, 0.6, 2.2, 0.7, 1.6, 1.0, 0.7, 0.8, 2.4, 1.7, 0.5, 1.1, 2.2, 0.9, 1.6, 1.8, 0.8, 2.3, 0.9,
           0.8, 1.0, 0.5, 1.6, 2.5, 2.2, 2.0, 1.3, 1.6, 1.2, 2.4, 0.9, 1.1, 0.8, 2.1, 2.2, 1.5, 2.4, 2.5, 2.2,
           1.3, 0.4, 1.5, 1.3, 1.7, 1.9, 1.8, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1.6, 0.9, 0.9, 2.5, 1.4, 1.3]
TimeStep = ['4h', '8h', '12h', '16h', '20h', '24h']

try:
    for GCM in ClimateModels:
        for RCP in ConcentrationPathway:
            BudwormCount = 1
            for budworm in BudwormList:
                year = 1971
                while year <= 2070:
                    if ((year%400 == 0) or ((year%4 == 0) and (year%100 != 0))):
                        days = 366
                    else:
                        days = 365
                    Dev_stage = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_Stage.tif")
                    Dev_stage_female = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_Stage_female.tif")
                    Dev_L2o = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L2o.tif")
                    Dev_L2 = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L2.tif")
                    Dev_L3 = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L3.tif")
                    Dev_L4 = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L4.tif")
                    Dev_L5 = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L5.tif")
                    Dev_L6_male = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L6_male.tif")
                    Dev_L6_female = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L6_female.tif")
                    Dev_pupa_male = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_pupa_male.tif")
                    Dev_pupa_female = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_pupa_female.tif")
                    L2_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_L2.tif")
                    L3_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_L3.tif")
                    L4_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_L4.tif")
                    L5_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_L5.tif")
                    L6_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_L6.tif")
                    pupa_male_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_pupa_male.tif")
                    pupa_female_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_pupa_female.tif")
                    adult_male_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_adult_male.tif")
                    adult_female_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_adult_female.tif")

                    current_day = 1
                    while current_day <= days:
                        for time in TimeStep:
                            tempfile = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\" + GCM + "\\" + RCP + "\\4hTempTimeStep\\" + time + "_" + str(current_day) + "_" + str(year) + ".tif")
                            Dev_L2o = Con(((Dev_stage == 1) & ((tempfile > 2.5) & (tempfile < 35)) & (Dev_L2o <= 1)), Dev_L2o + (float(budworm))*((0.194*((1/(1+(math.e**(3.00-(5.84*((tempfile-2.5)/(35-2.5)))))))-(math.e**((((tempfile-2.5)/(35-2.5))-1)/0.034))))/6), Dev_L2o)
                            Dev_L2 = Con(((Dev_stage == 2) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (Dev_L2 <= 1)), Dev_L2 + (float(budworm))*((0.919*((1/(1+(math.e**(2.91-(5.32*((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4)))))))-(math.e**((((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4))-1)/0.061))))/6), Dev_L2)
                            Dev_L3 = Con(((Dev_stage == 3) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (Dev_L3 <= 1)), Dev_L3 + (float(budworm))*((0.438*((1/(1+(math.e**(3.06-(6.85*((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4)))))))-(math.e**((((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4))-1)/0.061))))/6), Dev_L3)
                            Dev_L4 = Con(((Dev_stage == 4) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (Dev_L4 <= 1)), Dev_L4 + (float(budworm))*((1.211*((1/(1+(math.e**(3.80-(7.55*((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4)))))))-(math.e**((((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4))-1)/0.148))))/6), Dev_L4)
                            Dev_L5 = Con(((Dev_stage == 5) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (Dev_L5 <= 1)), Dev_L5 + (float(budworm))*((0.269*((1/(1+(math.e**(3.02-(8.57*((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4)))))))-(math.e**((((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4))-1)/0.005))))/6), Dev_L5)
                            Dev_L6_male = Con(((Dev_stage == 6) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (Dev_L6_male <= 1)), Dev_L6_male + (float(budworm))*((0.288*((1/(1+(math.e**(2.67-(5.03*((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4)))))))-(math.e**((((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4))-1)/0.151))))/6), Dev_L6_male)
                            Dev_L6_female = Con(((Dev_stage_female == 1) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (Dev_L6_female <= 1)), Dev_L6_female + (float(budworm))*((0.317*((1/(1+(math.e**(3.06-(4.66*((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4)))))))-(math.e**((((tempfile-4.4)/(38-4.4))-1)/0.136))))/6), Dev_L6_female)
                            Dev_pupa_male = Con(((Dev_stage == 7) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 35)) & (Dev_pupa_male <= 1)), Dev_pupa_male + ((0.259*((1/(1+(math.e**(2.75-(4.66*((tempfile-4.4)/(35-4.4)))))))-(math.e**((((tempfile-4.4)/(35-4.4))-1)/0.053))))/6), Dev_pupa_male)
                            Dev_pupa_female = Con(((Dev_stage_female == 2) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 35)) & (Dev_pupa_female <= 1)), Dev_pupa_female + ((0.205*((1/(1+(math.e**(2.85-(6.28*((tempfile-4.4)/(35-4.4)))))))-(math.e**((((tempfile-4.4)/(35-4.4))-1)/0.044))))/6), Dev_pupa_female)

                            Dev_stage = Con(((Dev_stage == 1) & (Dev_L2o > 1)), Dev_stage + 1, Dev_stage)
                            Dev_stage = Con(((Dev_stage == 2) & (Dev_L2 > 1)), Dev_stage + 1, Dev_stage)
                            Dev_stage = Con(((Dev_stage == 3) & (Dev_L3 > 1)), Dev_stage + 1, Dev_stage)
                            Dev_stage = Con(((Dev_stage == 4) & (Dev_L4 > 1)), Dev_stage + 1, Dev_stage)
                            Dev_stage = Con(((Dev_stage == 5) & (Dev_L5 > 1)), Dev_stage + 1, Dev_stage)
                            Dev_stage = Con(((Dev_stage == 6) & (Dev_L6_male > 1)), Dev_stage + 1, Dev_stage)
                            Dev_stage = Con(((Dev_stage == 7) & (Dev_pupa_male > 1)), Dev_stage + 1, Dev_stage)
                            Dev_stage_female = Con(((Dev_stage_female == 1) & (Dev_L6_female > 1)), Dev_stage_female + 1, Dev_stage_female)
                            Dev_stage_female = Con(((Dev_stage_female == 2) & (Dev_pupa_female > 1)), Dev_stage_female + 1, Dev_stage_female)

                            L2_date = Con(((Dev_L2o > 1) & (L2_date == 0)), L2_date + current_day, L2_date)
                            L3_date = Con(((Dev_L2 > 1) & (L3_date == 0)), L3_date + current_day, L3_date)
                            L4_date = Con(((Dev_L3 > 1) & (L4_date == 0)), L4_date + current_day, L4_date)
                            L5_date = Con(((Dev_L4 > 1) & (L5_date == 0)), L5_date + current_day, L5_date)
                            L6_date = Con(((Dev_L5 > 1) & (L6_date == 0)), L6_date + current_day, L6_date)
                            pupa_male_date = Con(((Dev_L6_male > 1) & (pupa_male_date == 0)), pupa_male_date + current_day, pupa_male_date)
                            adult_male_date = Con(((Dev_pupa_male > 1) & (adult_male_date == 0)), adult_male_date + current_day, adult_male_date)
                            pupa_female_date = Con(((Dev_L6_female > 1) & (pupa_female_date == 0)), pupa_female_date + current_day, pupa_female_date)
                            adult_female_date = Con(((Dev_pupa_female > 1) & (adult_female_date == 0)), adult_female_date + current_day, adult_female_date)

                        current_day = current_day + 1
                    L2_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\" + GCM + "_" + RCP + "_" + "Budworm_" + str(BudwormCount) + "_L2_" + str(year) + ".tif")
                    L3_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_" + str(BudwormCount) + "_L3_" + str(year) + ".tif")
                    L4_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_" + str(BudwormCount) + "_L4_" + str(year) + ".tif")
                    L5_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_" + str(BudwormCount) + "_L5_" + str(year) + ".tif")
                    L6_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_" + str(BudwormCount) + "_L6_" + str(year) + ".tif")
                    pupa_male_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_" + str(BudwormCount) + "_pupa_male_" + str(year) + ".tif")
                    adult_male_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_" + str(BudwormCount) + "_adult_male_" + str(year) + ".tif")
                    pupa_female_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_" + str(BudwormCount) + "_pupa_female_" + str(year) + ".tif")
                    adult_female_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_" + str(BudwormCount) + "_adult_female_" + str(year) + ".tif")

                    year = year + 1
                BudwormCount = BudwormCount + 1
            print GCM + " " + RCP + " has finished"
except Exception as e:
    print "An error occurred"
    print e

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print "A geoprocessing error occurred"
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)

except IndexError:
    print 'Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno)

arcpy.CheckInExtension('spatial')
```

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/229266/115

Answer (score 3):

#### First, fix the bug!

You're using `sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno` but you're not importing the `sys` module anywhere, so do that first !

Now, I'll start my review with a couple of style guides. You can read more about them [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

- use snake_case convention for your variable names
- `import`s should be grouped in the following order:

  - standard library imports
  - related third party imports
  - local application/library specific imports

You should put a blank line between each group of imports. More, absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages) if the import system is incorrectly configured

- don't add redundant parentheses in conditional statements
- use the `print()` function even if you're using Python 2.7.12
- add a <kbd>space</kbd> before and after each operator
- try to keep your lines no longer than 120 characters
- use string formatting when you're concatenating strings: e.g:

  ```
  print("Skiwi hates stacks {} times more than I do!".format(100))
  ```

With all of the above in mind, we'll have the following code (the formatting is a bit ugly because you have really long formulas but heh..):

```
import math
import sys

import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import Con, Raster

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('spatial')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

climate_models = ["CanESM2", "CSIRO-Mk3-6-0", "HadGEM2-ES"]
concentration_pathway = ["rcp26", "rcp45", "rcp85"]

budworm_list = [2.1, 2.3, 0.6, 2.1, 1.7, 1.1, 1.6, 2.4, 2.1, 2.2, 0.9, 1.6, 0.6, 2.0, 1.7, 0.6, 0.7, 1.8, 1.3, 2.4,
                2.1, 0.8, 2.2, 1.6, 0.5, 1.0, 1.6, 2.4, 2.5, 2.5, 0.8, 0.5, 2.5, 0.9, 1.2, 0.7, 1.8, 1.8, 0.4, 1.9,
                0.8, 1.3, 0.6, 2.2, 0.7, 1.6, 1.0, 0.7, 0.8, 2.4, 1.7, 0.5, 1.1, 2.2, 0.9, 1.6, 1.8, 0.8, 2.3, 0.9,
                0.8, 1.0, 0.5, 1.6, 2.5, 2.2, 2.0, 1.3, 1.6, 1.2, 2.4, 0.9, 1.1, 0.8, 2.1, 2.2, 1.5, 2.4, 2.5, 2.2,
                1.3, 0.4, 1.5, 1.3, 1.7, 1.9, 1.8, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1.6, 0.9, 0.9, 2.5, 1.4, 1.3]
time_step = ['4h', '8h', '12h', '16h', '20h', '24h']

try:
    for gcm in climate_models:
        for rcp in concentration_pathway:
            budworm_count = 1
            for budworm in budworm_list:
                year = 1971
                while year <= 2070:
                    if (year % 400 == 0) or ((year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0)):
                        days = 366
                    else:
                        days = 365
                    dev_stage = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_Stage.tif")
                    dev_stage_female = Raster(
                        "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_Stage_female.tif")
                    dev_l2o = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L2o.tif")
                    dev_l2 = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L2.tif")
                    dev_l3 = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L3.tif")
                    dev_l4 = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L4.tif")
                    dev_l5 = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L5.tif")
                    dev_l6_male = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L6_male.tif")
                    dev_l6_female = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_L6_female.tif")
                    dev_pupa_male = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_pupa_male.tif")
                    dev_pupa_female = Raster(
                        "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Dev_pupa_female.tif")
                    l2_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_L2.tif")
                    l3_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_L3.tif")
                    l4_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_L4.tif")
                    l5_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_L5.tif")
                    l6_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_L6.tif")
                    pupa_male_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_pupa_male.tif")
                    pupa_female_date = Raster(
                        "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_pupa_female.tif")
                    adult_male_date = Raster("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_adult_male.tif")
                    adult_female_date = Raster(
                        "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Jul_adult_female.tif")

                    current_day = 1
                    while current_day <= days:
                        for time in time_step:
                            tempfile = Raster(
                                "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\{}\\{}\\4hTempTimeStep\\{}_{}_{}.tif".format(
                                    gcm, rcp, time, current_day, year))
                            dev_l2o = Con(((dev_stage == 1) & ((tempfile > 2.5) & (tempfile < 35)) & (dev_l2o <= 1)),
                                          dev_l2o + (float(budworm)) * ((0.194 * (
                                          (1 / (1 + (math.e ** (3.00 - (5.84 * ((tempfile - 2.5) / (35 - 2.5))))))) - (
                                          math.e ** ((((tempfile - 2.5) / (35 - 2.5)) - 1) / 0.034)))) / 6), dev_l2o)
                            dev_l2 = Con(((dev_stage == 2) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (dev_l2 <= 1)),
                                         dev_l2 + (float(budworm)) * ((0.919 * (
                                         (1 / (1 + (math.e ** (2.91 - (5.32 * ((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4))))))) - (
                                         math.e ** ((((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4)) - 1) / 0.061)))) / 6), dev_l2)
                            dev_l3 = Con(((dev_stage == 3) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (dev_l3 <= 1)),
                                         dev_l3 + (float(budworm)) * ((0.438 * (
                                         (1 / (1 + (math.e ** (3.06 - (6.85 * ((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4))))))) - (
                                         math.e ** ((((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4)) - 1) / 0.061)))) / 6), dev_l3)
                            dev_l4 = Con(((dev_stage == 4) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (dev_l4 <= 1)),
                                         dev_l4 + (float(budworm)) * ((1.211 * (
                                         (1 / (1 + (math.e ** (3.80 - (7.55 * ((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4))))))) - (
                                         math.e ** ((((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4)) - 1) / 0.148)))) / 6), dev_l4)
                            dev_l5 = Con(((dev_stage == 5) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (dev_l5 <= 1)),
                                         dev_l5 + (float(budworm)) * ((0.269 * (
                                         (1 / (1 + (math.e ** (3.02 - (8.57 * ((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4))))))) - (
                                         math.e ** ((((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4)) - 1) / 0.005)))) / 6), dev_l5)
                            dev_l6_male = Con(
                                ((dev_stage == 6) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (dev_l6_male <= 1)),
                                dev_l6_male + (float(budworm)) * ((0.288 * (
                                (1 / (1 + (math.e ** (2.67 - (5.03 * ((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4))))))) - (
                                math.e ** ((((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4)) - 1) / 0.151)))) / 6), dev_l6_male)
                            dev_l6_female = Con(
                                ((dev_stage_female == 1) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 38)) & (dev_l6_female <= 1)),
                                dev_l6_female + (float(budworm)) * ((0.317 * (
                                (1 / (1 + (math.e ** (3.06 - (4.66 * ((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4))))))) - (
                                math.e ** ((((tempfile - 4.4) / (38 - 4.4)) - 1) / 0.136)))) / 6), dev_l6_female)
                            dev_pupa_male = Con(
                                ((dev_stage == 7) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 35)) & (dev_pupa_male <= 1)),
                                dev_pupa_male + ((0.259 * (
                                (1 / (1 + (math.e ** (2.75 - (4.66 * ((tempfile - 4.4) / (35 - 4.4))))))) - (
                                math.e ** ((((tempfile - 4.4) / (35 - 4.4)) - 1) / 0.053)))) / 6), dev_pupa_male)
                            dev_pupa_female = Con(((dev_stage_female == 2) & ((tempfile > 4.4) & (tempfile < 35)) & (
                            dev_pupa_female <= 1)), dev_pupa_female + ((0.205 * (
                            (1 / (1 + (math.e ** (2.85 - (6.28 * ((tempfile - 4.4) / (35 - 4.4))))))) - (
                            math.e ** ((((tempfile - 4.4) / (35 - 4.4)) - 1) / 0.044)))) / 6), dev_pupa_female)

                            dev_stage = Con(((dev_stage == 1) & (dev_l2o > 1)), dev_stage + 1, dev_stage)
                            dev_stage = Con(((dev_stage == 2) & (dev_l2 > 1)), dev_stage + 1, dev_stage)
                            dev_stage = Con(((dev_stage == 3) & (dev_l3 > 1)), dev_stage + 1, dev_stage)
                            dev_stage = Con(((dev_stage == 4) & (dev_l4 > 1)), dev_stage + 1, dev_stage)
                            dev_stage = Con(((dev_stage == 5) & (dev_l5 > 1)), dev_stage + 1, dev_stage)
                            dev_stage = Con(((dev_stage == 6) & (dev_l6_male > 1)), dev_stage + 1, dev_stage)
                            dev_stage = Con(((dev_stage == 7) & (dev_pupa_male > 1)), dev_stage + 1, dev_stage)
                            dev_stage_female = Con(((dev_stage_female == 1) & (dev_l6_female > 1)),
                                                   dev_stage_female + 1, dev_stage_female)
                            dev_stage_female = Con(((dev_stage_female == 2) & (dev_pupa_female > 1)),
                                                   dev_stage_female + 1, dev_stage_female)

                            l2_date = Con(((dev_l2o > 1) & (l2_date == 0)), l2_date + current_day, l2_date)
                            l3_date = Con(((dev_l2 > 1) & (l3_date == 0)), l3_date + current_day, l3_date)
                            l4_date = Con(((dev_l3 > 1) & (l4_date == 0)), l4_date + current_day, l4_date)
                            l5_date = Con(((dev_l4 > 1) & (l5_date == 0)), l5_date + current_day, l5_date)
                            l6_date = Con(((dev_l5 > 1) & (l6_date == 0)), l6_date + current_day, l6_date)
                            pupa_male_date = Con(((dev_l6_male > 1) & (pupa_male_date == 0)),
                                                 pupa_male_date + current_day, pupa_male_date)
                            adult_male_date = Con(((dev_pupa_male > 1) & (adult_male_date == 0)),
                                                  adult_male_date + current_day, adult_male_date)
                            pupa_female_date = Con(((dev_l6_female > 1) & (pupa_female_date == 0)),
                                                   pupa_female_date + current_day, pupa_female_date)
                            adult_female_date = Con(((dev_pupa_female > 1) & (adult_female_date == 0)),
                                                    adult_female_date + current_day, adult_female_date)

                        current_day = current_day + 1
                    l2_date.save(
                        "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\{}_{}_Budworm_{}_L2_{}.tif".format(gcm,
                                                                                                                  rcp,
                                                                                                                  budworm_count,
                                                                                                                  year))
                    l3_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_{}_L3_{}.tif".format(
                        budworm_count, year))
                    l4_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_{}_L4_{}.tif".format(
                        budworm_count, year))
                    l5_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_{}_L5_{}.tif".format(
                        budworm_count, year))
                    l6_date.save("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_{}_L6_{}.tif".format(
                        budworm_count, year))
                    pupa_male_date.save(
                        "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_{}_pupa_male_{}.tif".format(
                            budworm_count, year))
                    adult_male_date.save(
                        "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_{}_adult_male_{}.tif".format(
                            budworm_count, year))
                    pupa_female_date.save(
                        "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_{}_pupa_female_{}.tif".format(
                            budworm_count, year))
                    adult_female_date.save(
                        "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\PCIC_ClimateData\\TEST\\Budworm_{}_adult_female_{}.tif".format(
                            budworm_count, year))

                    year += 1
                budworm_count += 1
            print("{} {} has finished".format(gcm, rcp))
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred")
    print(e)

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print("A geoprocessing error occurred")
    print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))

except IndexError:
    print('Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno))

arcpy.CheckInExtension('spatial')
```

#### Code related improvements

- you said you want to generate a list of 100 random numbers (which should be the same while looping). That's quite easy to do if you're using the `random` module:

  ```
  def budworm_list(lower_limit, upper_limit, decimals):
      return [round(random.uniform(lower_limit, upper_limit), decimals) for _ in range(100)]
  ```

  Which can be latter called like this:

  ```
  budworm_list = generate_budworm_list(0.4, 2.5, 1)
  ```
- use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get rid of the usual counter. This Function can also take as a parameter the `step` which will let you start from 1.

  ```
  ...
  for budworm_count, budworm in enumerate(budworm_list, start=1):
      ...
  ```
- don't initialize the `year` each time you're looping. Instead, declare it at the top of the program. More, that's a constant, which is usually declared in UPPER_CASE. (`YEAR = 1971`). Better yet, remove completely the while loop and add a for loop (see below).
- there's a built-in which can tell you if an year is leap or not. You can find it in the calendar module:

  ```
  import calendar

  print calendar.isleap(1900)
  >> True
  ```

  So, let's make a little function which will return the number of days needed:

  ```
  def is_leap(year):
      return 366 if calendar.isleap(year) else 365
  ```
- your program is a big `main()` where you've written all the logic. This makes the whole **really** hard to read! Instead, write small functions for each specific task.
- your `while` loops can be re-written as `for` loops. This will save some variables allocation (extra incrementation):

  ```
  for year in range(1971, 2071):
      ...
      for current_day in range(1, days + 1):
          ...
  ```

I'd really like to review more of this, but unfortunately I can't test any of the code + you didn't add enough context (*for me*) to understand better what you'd like to achieve with each piece of code. For example, you create some variables in a for loop, and redefine them in another loop with the previous values from the previous loop... and so on.

Comment: Some more info. Simulating the development of 100 individual budworm throughout every year (each may have different growth rate, hence 100 random numbers). Calcs start Jan 1 and from then on if the temperature is between certain numbers (I have 4-hr timesteps through each day of each year), the development is incremented with the result of the equations. Once development is greater than 1, the budworm molts to the next larval stage, the julian date is recorded, and development is reset to 0. The next larval stage will have different parameters on how temperature affects the development.

Comment: Because temperature will vary between pixels, the development of a budworm will be spatially different, will molt to next larval stage at different times and will require the new parameters for calculating the development of next larval stage